# Changing WP-Config settings in Wordpress after successful installation

Tags: wordpress

Hello i have successfully installed my wordpress site with my very own custom theme and have everything working however i would like to implement some extra security measure to make sure my site is safe.

In the wp-config file we have a section like this:

```
define('AUTH_KEY',         '');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  '');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    '');
define('NONCE_KEY',        '');
define('AUTH_SALT',        '');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   '');
define('NONCE_SALT',       '');
```

Now what i want to know is if i change the 'key' and 'salt' values after having created users will this affect them? Will they still be able to login successfully into the wordpress admin backend.  The website is online so i would rather not try it myself that is why i decided to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't affect your current users in any way. You *may* find that you are temporarily logged out, but you can log straight back in.

You can get handily-generated salt keys here: https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/

Comment: Good deal - I tried it myself too (just to make sure) as I was setting up a new WP site at the very moment I saw your question.